# ActivityInfo set screen orientation

Tags: android, orientation

I got confused about the difference of the following usage:

1. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
2. SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE

I checked its explanation but have no idea about the difference between these tow.

Does this mean the second one will be passed through WindowOrientationListener to simulate the sensor value?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE` then it will not rely on the sensor, instead it will simply set an orientation called Landscape. When you use the other one, it will use the sensor, and you will have two different orientations. These are attributes and don't have any relation with the sensor value, I think. I suggest using `SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE`, simply because it gives more freedom to your user and has no extra programming cost.